# How to change letters in labels when clicked?

Tags: ios, swift

How to change letters in labels when clicked? 2 buttons for smaller letter or capital.

When we click small letter the label change to small letter and vice versa.

How to do that? I try some code but I am stuck.

[image]

```
let ABC = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]

var str: Character = "Z"

//@IBOutlet weak var capitalABC: UIButton!
// @IBOutlet weak var smallac: UIButton!
// @IBOutlet weak var Abclbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Abclbl: UILabel!
// @IBOutlet weak var Abclbl: Le!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Abclbl.text = ABC[0]

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func ABCPre(sender: AnyObject) {
    if Abclbl.text == "a"
    {
        print("Do nothing")
    }
    else
    {
        let preVal = self.Abclbl.text!
        var inde = ABC.indexOf(preVal)
        inde = inde! - 1
        let get = ABC[inde!]
        Abclbl.text = get
        alphReocg(Abclbl.text!)
    }
}

func ABCNext(sender: AnyObject) {
    //let str: String = "Z"
    if Abclbl.text! == String(str)
    {
        print("Do nothing")
    }
    else
    {
        let preVal = self.Abclbl.text!
        var inde = ABC.indexOf(preVal)
        inde = inde! + 1
        let get = ABC[inde!]
        Abclbl.text = get
        alphReocg(Abclbl.text!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What problem exactly are you having with the code you posted?

Comment: yes. the question is not clearly understandable

Comment: Sounds like part of your questing involves changing the case of a string. `String` has a [`lowercased()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1641392-lowercased) and [`uppercased()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1640996-uppercased) functions.

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between Small latter and capital latter when you try yo get the index of like   `inde = ABC.indexOf("a")` it will return **nil** but when you try to get this way `inde = ABC.indexOf("A")` it will return **0** 
I have little bit changes in your function and this function handle Small And Capital later both functionality
Try this 
First you need to add one flag variable which handle which button press(Small or Capital)
like this way

```
var isCapital = true
```

After adding above variable  your functionality like bellow

```
func ABCCapital(sender: AnyObject) {
    isCapital = true
    let currentValue = self.Abclbl.text!
    Abclbl.text = currentValue.capitalized

}
func ABCSmall(sender: AnyObject) {
    isCapital = false
    let currentValue = self.Abclbl.text!
    Abclbl.text = currentValue.lowercaseString

}

func ABCPre(sender: AnyObject) {
    if Abclbl.text == "a" || Abclbl.text == "A"
    {
        print("Do nothing")
    }
    else
    {
        let preVal = self.Abclbl.text!
        if isCapital == true {
            var inde = ABC.indexOf(preVal)
            inde = inde! - 1
            let get = ABC[inde!]
            Abclbl.text = get
        } else {
            var inde = ABC.indexOf(preVal.capitalized)
            inde = inde! - 1
            let get = ABC[inde!]
            Abclbl.text = get.lowercaseString
        }
        alphReocg(Abclbl.text!)
    }
}

func ABCNext(sender: AnyObject) {
    //let str: String = "Z"
    if Abclbl.text! == "Z" || Abclbl.text! == "z"
    {
        print("Do nothing")
    }
    else
    {
        let preVal = self.Abclbl.text!
        if isCapital == true {
            var inde = ABC.indexOf(preVal)
            inde = inde! + 1
            let get = ABC[inde!]
            Abclbl.text = get
        } else {
            var inde = ABC.indexOf(preVal.capitalized)
            inde = inde! + 1
            let get = ABC[inde!]
            Abclbl.text = get.lowercaseString
        }

        alphReocg(Abclbl.text!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Actuallu task is when we click small button we get small alphapets in label and when we click pre button it get(f,e,d,c,b,a) and we click next button we get (a,b,c,d,e,f) if we click capital button we can get capital alphabets.

Comment: you have not added Capital & Small Button Action please add both action then i will update my answer

Comment: i have updated my answer.you can checkout my updated  answer.

Comment: HI jignesh. it getting use of local variable alpharecog before its declaration error in alphReocg(Abclbl.text!)
    }

Answer (score 0):

if you need to simply convert text into lowercase and upercase then convert your string in button click method like bellow

for swift 3.0 first import foundation

```
import Foundation
```

then in your button click action

```
 func uppercase(sender: AnyObject) {

    var title = "Text That you need to convert " 
    title.uppercased() // "TEXT THAT YOU NEED TO CONVERT"
}
```

For Lowercase

```
   func lowercase(sender: AnyObject) {

    var title = "Text That you need to convert" 
    title.lowercased() // "text that you need to convert"
}
```